# How to change confirmation_url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise sends to mail instruction for account confirmation. When the user clicks on the Confirmation link, their account is activated and the user gets redirected to the `static_pages#home` page, but i need that this link redirect to other page.

Confirmation url:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Подтвердить мой аккаунт', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

confirmation_controller:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  # GET /resource/confirmation/new
   def new
     super
   end

  # POST /resource/confirmation
   def create
     super
   end

  # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
   def show
     super
   end

   protected

  # The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
   def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
     super(resource_name)
   end

  # The path used after confirmation.
   def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
     new_profiles_path (resource_name, resource)
   end

end
```

New error in browser:

> /home/vlad/Desktop/MyApp/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:26:
>   syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' new_profiles_path
>   (resource_name, resource) ^

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to change `confirmation_url` instead you need to override `after_confirmation_path_for`

To do that you need to define  `after_confirmation_path_for` in `ConfirmationsController`

To do that create  `confirmations_controller.rb` in `app/controllers` directory:

```
class ConfirmationsController     < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  private

  def     after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
        your_new_after_confirmation_path
  end

end
```

In `config/routes.rb`, add this line so that Devise will use your custom ConfirmationsController.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
```

Restart the web server, and you should have it.

Please refer [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users) for more options/details

**updated**

Here is `confirmations_controller.rb`

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
# GET /resource/confirmation/new
def new
 super
end
# POST /resource/confirmation
def create
  super
end

# GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
def show
 super
end

protected # The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
 super(resource_name)
end

# The path used after confirmation.
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
 new_profiles_path(resource_name, resource)
end
end
```

Comment: after your instruction new error - /home/vlad/Desktop/MyApp/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' new_profiles_path (resource_name, resource) ^

Comment: This is my code for now: protected def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
     new_profiles_path (resource_name, resource)
   end

Comment: It looks like you have introduced a syntax error. Please paste your code snippet for `confirmations_controller.rb` in your question. In comment its not that readable

Comment: You have added an extra space after `new_profiles_path` please remove that

Comment: i remove extra space and now other error in browser: undefined method `new_profiles_path' for #<Users::ConfirmationsController:0x000000019b0838>

Comment: Thats because you have not defined any routes which map to `new_profiles_path`  , you need a valid url to redirect to.

Comment: you mean replace 'new_profiles_path' to /profiles/new url?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to redirect to after confirmation? If you want the user to login then you need `new_session_path(resource_name)` if you want to goto signup page then you need `new_registration_path(resource_name)`

Comment: Run `rake routes` in rails console and paste the output here in your question